# How to synchronize a Jframe show in others computer is same as host?

Tags: java

My project having a Jframe that showing some gui, the gui will represent a user or agent to move into the map. My Jframe will keep refreshing to make the user GUI moving on the map, and it have location to move with.

Now I will need to implement the GUI to show in others computer. If i successfully send the information and create a new user to show in the MAP GUI of the host by just a button, any idea how I show the entire map of the host?

I need to show the Jframe at host when user access. But i got no idea what kind of thing i need to use to keep synchronize and show it? If i not planing to use java applet, what others can perform this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/TOC.html) should be sufficient. However, when it comes to network programming, you have several choices within the [Java EE](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/intro_ee5/) libraries